# lightgallery does not work with dynamically generated elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, lightgallery

I have implement lighgallery plugin to my local site... and this is not working with dom elements ...

for example

1.) append dom element created with js to html code..

if i create something like this in js `"<span id='imgcon'><a href="image"><img src="image"></a></span>"` and this all code is in a varialbe lets call galleryview (`var galleryview`) and this variable i append to  a div that is in html file `<html><head></head><bdy><div class="container"></div></bdy></html>` and append like this from js file code `$(".container").append(galleryview);` and in end i use this `$(".imgcon").lightGallery();` does not work...

Here is [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/o0y70kv0/) not working with dom

2.) images are in html code

i have html code smthing like this `<html><head></head><bdy><div class="container"><span class="imgcont"><a href="image"><img src="image"></a></span></bdy></html>`
This works fine as it.`$(".imgcon").lightGallery();`

Here is [jsfiddle working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6oun2u2w/1/) without dom.

**Question** : why i cannot use dom with lightgallery ?

First demo is not working becasue i use js dom and second demo is working because i use html code in html file.. or there any problem with my code..

Comment: yes i was writing fast so i wrote abbravtion

Comment: <im> what is it ? what means ?

Comment: ok, btw have u understand qeustion or i have to explain ??

Comment: You're always appending the `[1]`th image from Array... so I don't understand what's your issue.

Comment: it doesnot matter from array... i want to know why first code is not working with lightgallery ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put your `$(".imagecontiner").lightGallery();` **inside** the `click` handler

http://jsfiddle.net/o0y70kv0/1/

The above will work only for the **first** dynamically created gellery.
**To make it work for multiple elements:** pre-create in-memory appendable elements and assign to each the `.lightGallery()` instance

http://jsfiddle.net/o0y70kv0/6/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var imagesarray = [
        "http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/Winter-Tiger-Wild-Cat-Images.jpg",
        "http://www.gettyimages.ca/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Category-Creative/UK/UK_Creative_462809583.jpg",
        "http://blog.jimdo.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/tree-247122.jpg",
        "http://i765.photobucket.com/albums/xx291/just-meller/national%20geografic/Birds-national-geographic-6873734-1600-1200.jpg",
        "http://www.gettyimages.com/gi-resources/images/CreativeImages/Hero-527920799.jpg"
    ];

    var hiddenimages = "",
            albumcover;

    $("#appendnewcontainer").click(function() {

        $("<span />", {
            class : "container",
            appendTo : $("#fotoappendarea"),
            append : $("<span />", {
                class : "imagecontiner",
                html : "<a class='dfed' href=" + imagesarray[1] + "><img src='" + imagesarray[1] + "' class='_34'/></a>"
            }).lightGallery()
        });

    });
});
```

Comment: whyyyy  i should use in ??

Comment: @Phoenix the above will work only on the first append, for multiple appends wait a second to improve my answer :D

Comment: ok this works for me but http://jsfiddle.net/o0y70kv0/1/ this works too for every append item http://jsfiddle.net/o0y70kv0/5/

Comment: @Phoenix if you append more than one, the 2nd, 3rd etc are not clickable AKA: will not trigget the gallery. Use my extended answer example for multiple dynamic galleries.

Comment: @Phoenix ohh well than :D

Comment: @Phoenix no, believe me. you have CSS issues. Using the first code, all other "containers" will not trigger the gallery see for your self: http://jsfiddle.net/o0y70kv0/7/. Again, use my extended example.

Answer (score 0):

when you generated gallery item after than you need to use below code in your project

```
    var $methods = $('#gallery-container');

$methods.lightGallery();
$methods.data('lightGallery').destroy(true);
$methods.lightGallery({
    thumbnail: true,
    animateThumb: true,
    showThumbByDefault: true,
});
```